# Tensorflow code on google cloud platform

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, cpu-usage

I am facing a strange issue. I have a working code for a very simple neural network. I am running it on my laptop. Kind of slow but ok. I then created a 24 cores instance (Linux) on google cloud, and run the same code. It seems to take almost the same time. I expected to be a *lot* faster. Any idea why this could be the case? I am using a standard, vanilla pip installation of cpu tensorflow. Nothing fancy.
Would appreciate any ideas...

Best, Umberto

Comment: If the code is the same running on your laptop and on Google Cloud, there will not be a difference in performance. In order to increase performance on Google Cloud you will need to change your code to utilize the cores that are available there.

Comment: Imagined as much... Any pointer on how to do so?

Comment: I assume that you are using a framework to construct your neural network, if so, which one? Also you can look into using the GPUs to train your network, this will greatly improve your network's time to train and evaluate.

Comment: Sorry... Forgot to mention that. I am using tensorflow. Nothing fancy, just plain standard tensorflow. Is a very dummy model (feed forward NN with one hidden layer and softmax)... Thanks.

Comment: No problem, here is a link that could be helpful https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/using-gpus Tensorflow will automatically prioritize to use the GPU over the CPU so you don't need to change anything about your actual code. Best of luck!